# How to mantain a JVM pointer in a DllMain call and prevent call JNI_CreateJavaVM twice

Tags: java, c++, dll, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm loading a DLL and another program call a function I created. This function I made calls some java functions via JNI.

PS: I don't have the control of the DLL method call, it is called my another program.

When I create the JVM I do it with: JNI_CreateJavaVM.

After calling JNI methods I destroy the JVM with:
JNI_DestroyJVM().

**The problem is that when the function in DLL is called, I create the JVM. But if the JVM is already loaded if fails becasuse of the following problem:**

---

The problem:
[Re-calling JNI_CreateJavaVM returns -1 after calling DestroyJavaVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486486/re-calling-jni-createjavavm-returns-1-after-calling-destroyjavavm)

I know I can't call the JNI_CreateJavaVM twice because:
JNI_DestroyJVM(), it said "[The JDK/JRE still does not support VM unloading, however](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp16553)." Just don't call it, and don't re-initialize it either.

---

1 - Why The JVM is still loaded in the memory after the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH?

2 - Is there a way to store a global variable in the DllMain?
Maybe I could store the (JavaVM *jvm); pointer, and not destroy the jvm after the dll call, so it would be destroyed when the process that call the dll is destroyed.

As I don't have the main program, I just have the DLL call, I can't store a global variable because the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH deletes every variable I created before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not call `JNI_DestroyJVM` if you wish to run Java code more than once during the process lifecycle. Call [`DetachCurrentThread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#DetachCurrentThread) instead.
- Before calling `JNI_CreateJavaVM` make sure JVM is not already created. Use [`JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs) to get an instance of the loaded JVM, then [`AttachCurrentThread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#AttachCurrentThread) to get `JNIEnv*` handle.